# How can debugging with alert solve (undefined) timing issue?

Tags: javascript, debugging, alert, timing

I am experiencing some behaviour from a web application that I cannot clarify: adding alert lines to debug it actually "solves" the issue as the error does not occur. The relevant parts of the story are as follows:

I have an init method, a function displaying content and a "main" function, something like (note that a is a global variable, part of a namespace)
PS: It turns out my minimal example equivalent was missing some essential part, which was causing the issue.

```
a = undefined;

init = function() {
     if ( a === undefined ) { a = new A } //global variable 
     alert("1 - a gets defined");
}

//method is part of A when A is constructed
A.show = function() {...}

//PS: the call to init() was part of a content-dependant method where init was skipped altogether when no content was loaded yet.
updateContent = function(){
    if (noDataLoaded()) {return;}
    init(); //PS: Init has been moved before the content check
    performUpdatesAccordingToContent();
}

main() {
    updateContent();
    alert("2 - trying to display a");
    a.show();
}
```

If executed as above: alert 1 is shown, then alert 2, then contents of a get displayed.
If executed without the alerts the following error is thrown, breaking the app:

```
TypeError: a is undefined
```

All functions are called after the document ready event is fired, as far as I can tell and the alert lines were added to check for proper order of execution.

Question is then how adding the alert lines can resolve the initialization issue? then: how to solve it without them?

Comment: `new A` will initialise an `A` with its _prototype_, but `show` is defined on the constructor, and therefor not inherited. Is it fixed when you use `A.prototype.show = function(){ ... }`? And alerts should and _will_ make no difference on code execution, so look in other directions for errors.

Comment: While it's important to create a reduced example, your code is invalid and doesn't make sense. Obviously this is not what you're running since you say it works with the `alert()`. Post an actual representation of the issue.

Comment: If an alert makes a difference to your code, the only possible reason I can think of would be if you are doing something asynchronous, like loading a local file, or mixing libraries like angular and jquery, so that  you get timing differences. I've had the same thing happen to me, but usually it turns out the alert thing is a red herring, and the issue is with the order of events.

Comment: Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

I will hazard a guess that could be wrong since I don't know what your code is doing, but alert() could be allowing async behavior in init() to resolve itself before show() is fired.

Comment: [Here's a complete example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltt0ra3u/) that shows it works without the `alert()`.

Comment: @squint what I posted is the minimal example equivalent of my code which is harder to minimalise as it involves libraries like jquery, leaflet and custom components.

Comment: @Fat_Freddy it was also my guess that something is going on asynchronously... still digging into it and thanks for the hints confirming my suspect

Comment: @Damon it was also my guess that something is going on asynchronously... still digging into it and thanks for the hints confirming my suspect

Comment: @Damon I think you were definitely right, even though I did not manage to sort it out completely. It looks like with the alert some content would get loaded, allowing the updateContent function (added with edit) to call init before the alert2 got shown (delaying access to the previously undefined variable).

Comment: You can resolve that by properly setting up your callbacks or with a setTimeout hack which would do the same thing as the alert, just without a visual confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've collected so far and thanks to @Damon, @Fat_Freddy and @squint (Reviewing the code path for completeness of the minimal example actually helped a lot figuring out part of the solution), here follows a sum-it-up answer.

Using alert to debug code adds a large delay in the main thread while it waits for user input. This can give time to background work in the event queue to complete, changing the status of the window (which in my case allowed proper initialization). So in general, if adding alerts changes the behaviour of your webapp it means you have to look for components of it that can be influenced by background events.

If there are no asynchronous calls involved (ajax) or events queued that can affect your app status, then alerts cannot change the behaviour of a webapp.